# jQuery Get value from multi dimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I can't really find a good match for this question,

I have this task of getting the values from this elements

```
Card record 1 :
<input type="text" name="card[][company]" />
<input type="text" name="card[][bank]" />
<input type="text" name="card[][hospital]" />

Card record 2 :
<input type="text" name="card[][company]" />
<input type="text" name="card[][bank]" />
<input type="text" name="card[][hospital]" />
```

I want to get their values to be like this so I can pass it on to my controller via AJAX (CI)

```
[0] 
    card[0][company] = ABC
    card[1][bank] = DEF
    card[2][hospital] = GHI
[1] 
    card[0][company] = ABC
    card[1][bank] = DEF
    card[2][hospital] = GHI
```

I have tried $.each with .push and .map but can't really figure out the correct manipulation, JQUERY answers please.

Comment: can't you just use `serialize()` on the form and let jQuery do all the heavy lifting internally?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this

```
var arr = $('input[name^=card]').map(function(){
   return { this.name : this.value }
}).get(), newArr = [];
while(arr.length > 0)
  newArr.push(arr.splice(0 , 3));
```

`newArr` will contain what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, there is no concept of multidimensional array. But you can use it same functionality with array of array.
Like while declaring
Var are=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
Here you can access array elements as follows

Var a=are[0] returns [1,2,3]
Var b =a[0] returns 1
So if you want to push some data you need to push in initial array which is array of array. And here initial array can be used for any array manipulation.